# JS adding to cart

Tags: javascript, postgresql, laravel

Hi i am trying to let user to add selected item into carts table. I have tried alot of things but so far no results. I am using postgresql

here is my html file

```
 <form method="post" action="/products/shopping_cart">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5 style="color: #18BC9C;" id="productName"> <strong>{{ this.productname }} </strong></h5>

                    <img src="/{{ this.photofile }}" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="" style="width:400px;height:450px;">

                    <p> "{{ this.description }}" </p>
                    <hr>
                    <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                        <li id="quantity">Stock:
                            <strong> {{ this.quantity }} remaining
                            </strong>
                        </li>
                        <li id="price">Price:
                            <strong> ${{ this.price }} NZD
                            </strong>
                        </li>
                        <li>Shipping:
                            <strong> ${{ this.shippingvalue }} NZD
                            </strong>
                        </li>
                        <br>
                        <li id="category">Style:
                            <strong> {{ this.category }}
                            </strong>
                        </li>
                        <li id="gender">For:
                            <strong>  {{ this.gender }}
                            </strong>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right: 20px;">Add to cart</button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
```

< form>

and here is my js

```
client.query(
        'INSERT into cartstable(price,description,productname,uniqueid,  category, gender, size,   quantity, shippingValue, dateadded) Values ((SELECT price FROM productstable WHERE price=($1)),$2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9,$10)', 
         [ price,description,productname,uniqueid, category, gender,size,  quantity, shippingValue,  date]
        );
```

Comment: Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know at all but you can do it to use ajax

Example:

Create a route:

```
Route::post('add-to-cart/{product}', CartController@addToCart);
```

In cart controller:

```
public function addToCart($product){
  //if you use data as a string
  $data = $product->split(";")

  \App\Cart::create([
    'product_id' => data[0],
    'quantity' => .....,
    'user_id' => .....,\
    ..........
  ]);
}
```

Ajax:

```
$('#addToCart').click(function(){
//you can use javascript to get data from html

var data= "";
data += product_id + ";";
//or some thing you like to store in data
//You can use data as a array

  $.ajax({
     url: "{{ url('add-to-cart') }}" + '/' + data,
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
       "_token" : {{csrf_token()}},
       "data" : data
     },
    success: function(data){
      //Do some code to update cart on html
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: so it it like 'product_id' => data[0], quantity=>data[1] etc?  looking at your code whereabouts do you call the database? @VuHoangDuc

Comment: Right, you must control data you transfer on js. 
For example, you use array to store `var data=[]` `data.push($('#price').text())` ...ect..
or `var data= ""` `data+=$('#price').text() + ";"`
In controller, you use dd($product) to see data you transfer and handle it@dsvjksv